# Javascript multiline regex lookahead OR the rest of string / very end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble capturing all groups in the following markdown text:

```
### AAA
text for group AAA

### BBB
text for group BBB

### CCC
text for group CCC
```

The regex I'm currently using is:

```
/(^###\s[\s\S]*?(?=^###\s))/gm
```

Which uses a positive lookahead to know when to cut off each group. As a result though, it always fails to capture the last group (there's no lookahead match).

The newline characters won't be consistent, so I can't rely on those, and javascript regex doesn't have \Z (which I believe is "very end of string" in other languages, as opposed to $ which is end of line).

How can I capture all groups here?

Comment: what do you want to capture? show us input and output expected please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use negative look-ahead instead of positive : the content of a group will be every character that isn't at the beginning of a `###` string.

`^###\s((?!###)[\s\S])*`

Try it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fD0kN6/3) !

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See if JS has the `\z` construct.
If not, you could use a lookahead for *not* a character (EOS)
`(?![\S\s])` inside your existing lookahead.

`(^###[^\S\r\n][\S\s]*?(?=^###[^\S\r\n]|(?![\S\s])))`

Formatted:

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      ^ \#\#\# [^\S\r\n] 
      [\S\s]*? 
      (?=
           ^ \#\#\# [^\S\r\n]  
        |  (?! [\S\s] )
      )
 )                             # (1 end)
```